# Inheritance is changing previous folder from sub folder and all subfolders within. Even though inheritance is disabled?

Tags: windows-server-2019, ntfs

The title pretty much says it, I am testing ABE in my test area. I have created a folder series:

SharedLocation\testDestination\Test4\test5\test10\

inside test10 are three more folders. test14 test15 and test16.
The problem is, when I modify the rights to test 14, it changes test10, test15, and test16.
Is this expected normal NTFS behavior? Or is something going on that I am not aware of?

This is on Windows Server 2019 Standard 1809

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 12/18/23 : Steps to changing File Permissions

I Was asked to include this section,

The way I am handling the tests is to do it manually via the File Explorer on the local server via RDP (if that matters), "Properties" > "Security" > "Advanced" > "Add/Remove"

I am using my Global Admin account for this action.
This is on the Domain Controller itself.

Comment: Tell us the steps to change the permissions. Are you doing this local or over the network? Command prompt or Windows Explorer?

Comment: @GregAskew I've added my process, just been doing it manually, due to the nature of the tests.

Comment: You need to include if you are doing this local, or remote through UNC path. UNC it is expected behavior, and it sometimes warns of it

Comment: @GregAskew I am logging into the server itself via RDP, working on the local server as a global admin, this particular server is the domain controller also, probably should have mentioned that before hand.